# Delete data from a collection in mongo db by using multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongo db
using i have to delete data from a table like

```
select from table where id=12 and browser =GC
```

But I dont know how to perform this in mongo db?

Comment: [Mongo Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) has pleny of examples you should be looking at first

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [remove](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

```
db.collectionName.remove({'_id':12,'browser':"GC"})
```

Can provide more accurate answer if you show your collection and documents .